# Eclipse as git mergetool?

Tags: eclipse, git, configuration, mergetool

Let's say I'm using Eclipse with command line git.

If I have an Eclipse instance running, is it possible to use its internal comparison view as `mergetool` somehow? I'm not sure if it is even possible because of the required exit code.

(*I want to avoid installing the Egit plugin, I have some negative experience with that.*)

Thanks for any hints!

**Update** Well, there seems to be no way for doing this wrt the command line. Anyway, I believe I'll give the EGit plugin another chance because of the merging features within Eclipse. In case someone finds an alternative solution, please don't hesitate to post it here!

Comment: Note that this is simply an omission of Eclipse.  If they were to expose a command-line interface to their merge functionality then you certainly could use git with it.  You might open an enhancement request with Eclipse to ask for that functionality to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Eclipse this way.